# Get the value for one object given the value of another object in JSON and Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Given this JSON:

```
{
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName" : "doe",
    "age"      : 26,
    "address"  :
    {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
         "city"         : "Nara",
         "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
     },
     "phoneNumbers":
     [
         {
             "type"  : "iPhone",
             "number": "0123-4567-8888"
         },
         {
             "type"  : "home",
             "number": "0123-4567-8910"
         }
     ]
 }
```

Is there a way in Angularjs to get the value of "number" when the value of "type" is equal to iPhone OR home?

I think this would be pretty easy to do with something like JSONPath but I'm having a hard time getting JSONPath to play nicely with Angular. If there is an easy way to do it in Angular I love to hear about it.

Comment: question is far too vague without some context

Comment: I'm not sure I could be any more clear. I want to find out the value for number or "0123-4567-8888" given that I know the value for type is iPhone.

Comment: in what use case? A user event? Display filter? Look for one or look for all?  Context is still lacking. Normally would provide some markup to provide that context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $filter service just don't forget to inject it into controller. please see here:

http://jsbin.com/nacam/1/edit?html,js,output

```
 app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope, $filter){

  $scope.user = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName" : "doe",
    "age"      : 26,
    "address"  :
    {
        "streetAddress": "naist street",
         "city"         : "Nara",
         "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
     },
     "phoneNumbers":
     [
         {
             "type"  : "iPhone",
             "number": "0123-4567-8888"
         },
         {
             "type"  : "home",
             "number": "0123-4567-8910"
         }
     ]
 };
  //I've made assumption that only one number exist for iphone but of not you just get first one
  $scope.iphoneNumber = ($filter('filter')($scope.user.phoneNumbers, "iPhone"))[0].number;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to access the phoneNumbers array of the object.

So something like this.

```
obj = { ..your object.. }

var phoneNumbers = obj.phoneNumbers;
```

If you are doing this in markup, you could use an angular filter with the pipe syntax.

```
 {{ expression | filter }}
```

If you are doing this in the controller, you can still use an angular filter with the controller syntax:

```
$filter('filtername')(arg1,arg2);
```

Here is a link to filters.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Filters are very powerful can you can even write your own custom filters to do pretty much whatever you need.

Hope this helps.